# Выборка данных с двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо выбрать данные двух таблиц(`chat` и `users`). При этом с таблицы юзерс мне необходимо поле логин, которое в таблице чат указано как id пользователя в юзерс. Однако массив `SELECT * FROM chat LEFT JOIN users ON chat.author = users.id WHERE chat.room = номер комнаты ORDER BY chat.id` возвращает

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ctime] => 1468691947
            [author] => 1
            [title] => 
            [room] => 1
            [message] => 11111
            [login] => admin
            [password] => 1683bed6dd5702c3a6a5982da26ee19e
            [reg_time] => 1468669491
            [real_name] => Serhiy
            [about] => i am not in danger! i am the danger!
            [email] => milo@sobaka.lomaka
            [active] => 1
            [role] => 1
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [ctime] => 1468691942
        [author] => 1
        [title] => 
        [room] => 1
        [message] => asdasdasd
        [login] => admin
        [password] => 1683bed6dd5702c3a6a5982da26ee19e
        [reg_time] => 1468669491
        [real_name] => Serhiy
        [about] => i am not in danger! i am the danger!
        [email] => milo@sobaka.lomaka
        [active] => 1
        [role] => 1
    )`
```

При этом необходимо чтобы в массиве id был не автора сообщения а сообщения. Помогите составить запрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT *` делает выборку всех полей..`SELECT chat.id FROM chat JOIN users ON chat.author = users.id WHERE chat.room = номер комнаты ORDER BY chat.id` остальные поля при необходимости указывай через кому `table.column`.

Comment: работает, но можно ли организовать запрос так что-бы с первой таблици выдирались все данные, и со второй все кроме полей которые есть в первой, дабы они не перезаписывались?